# Show that the lower limit topology with rationals is different than lower limit topology with reals

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topology with basis $\{[a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and the topology $\{[a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I know that $[\sqrt{2},2)$ is open in the lower limit topology generated by the reals.

How do I prove that it is not open in the lower limit topology generated by rationals. Couldn't a union of elements in the rational lower limit topology approximate $[\sqrt{2},2)$?

Comment: Even without a specific example it's clear the topologies are not equal: the lower limit topology is not second countable (it's weight is $\mathfrak{c}$, even) , while this rational lower limit topology is second countable by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were open in the lower limit topology generated by rationals, there would exist a basis element $[a, b)$ (with $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$) contained in $[\sqrt2, 2)$ such that $\sqrt2 \in [a, b)$. Evidently, this is impossible, since for any $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \ni b > a$ such that $a > \sqrt2$, the interval $[a, b)$ cannot contain $\sqrt 2$.